# Any remote debugger to inspect a running Android app layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, layout

I am looking for a way to inspect an running Android application layout (preferably, by dp/sp), like something as you can see in those Google Chrome/Firefox/Safari live HTML inspector feature.

I have an Android app which needs to follow a strict design guideline and comparing between the guideline and the application itself is quite cumbersome and taking a lot of time to jump around multiple source codes and layout .xml(s) to check a design conformity, so it'd be very efficient to have such debugger.

I should also mention that the app needs specific Android devices to run (unable to run on an simulator or unapproved devices).

Your ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this built-in feature in android studio run the app and after click on the layout inspector "
[image]

Comment: I didn't have Android Stuido installed, can layout inspector inspect other people's app?